# How to convert data in table format to pivot format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I would need help in converting table which is in table format to a pivot format. Below is the sample data which I have:

```
Product     Currency    Value   US   UK   Japan     Ind  Local  MNC
Product 1    USD         200    56%  22%    0%      13%   68%    19%
Product 2    USD         300    67%  18%    15%      0%   85%    15%
Product 3    GBP         400    13%  68%    19%     67%   18%    15%
```

I need in the output in the below format:

```
Product    Currency Value 1 Region   Customer     Value 2   Value 3
Product 1   USD      200    US         Ind           56%    13%
Product 1   USD      200    US         Local         56%    68%
Product 1   USD      200    US         MNC           56%    19%
Product 1   USD      200    UK         Ind           22%    13%
Product 1   USD      200    UK         Local         22%    68%
Product 1   USD      200    UK         MNC           22%    19%
Product 1   USD      200    Japan      Ind            0%    13%
Product 1   USD      200    Japan      Local          0%    68%
Product 1   USD      200    Japan      MNC            0%    19%
```

If you see for each row of `Product 1`, I need three rows of country and for three rows of customer type. The only exception is if either of country of customer type is `0%` we can ignore those cells. So for example from the above output table we may not need the `Japan` rows because `Japan` is given as `0%` for `Product 1`

Similarly for `Product 2`, we may not need `Individual` rows because it is given as zero. I do not know how to write vb codes, so tried recording macro, however because of huge volume of data, the macro does not work.

Also, if it is helpful

Part A - Consists of Product, Currency and Value
Part B - US, UK and Japan - basically lists out few countries
Part C - Customer type - includes Ind, Local, MNC

Comment: I do not know to write VBA codes, so i tried recording macro. So created multiple rows for all the combinations and then used the index and match formula and also sumif formula. But end of it, the excel hang because of the large volume of the data. If I create all combination it would come upto 10 lakh rows so it so it is not working.

Comment: If the values are always the same, you could try recording a macro and starting there. Using a `for each` loop might work.

Comment: Hi Raystafarian, When you mention the values i guess you meant the column headings (ex.product, currency, value, US, japan etc). If yes, the values or heading would be constant. 

The one problem i get with recording the macro is creating rows for example creating 9 rows for each product 1. I have around 10 lakhs rows (in actual data), and then using the index and match formula. This i am not sure off and i have the least knowledge on writing codes.

Comment: I have the data in excel file, which i am unable to upload here, so if you let me know your email id, i can send the file to you. or let me know of any way i can share the file with you.

Comment: Can someone help me out on this? Raystafarian would it be possible to write a code for me?

Comment: @Raystafarian would it be possible to help me by creating the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I can't work directly on your workbook. Perhaps you could try to work on a snippet of VBA code for a portion of your data and then ask how to expand it to the entire worksheet?

Comment: Sure. Would it be possible to creating the code for the first part where in my output mentioned above, how can i get the from column "product" to "customer type". Once i get that, i will record the macro  using index and match function and then loop it.

Comment: I got below code, but the problem is that it will work if i have only two tables, however i am not sure how to modify it to include three tables. In above case, it would work if I had only part A and Part B

Link for the data: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_database_table_from_a_summary_table/

Link for Macro code:
http://spreadsheetpage.com/downloads/xl/makedatabasetable.txt

Comment: I wrote another macro, I hope it helps you ;).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code, please try it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub customePivot()
    Call makePivot(Sheets("Sheet1"), Sheets("Sheet2"))
End Sub

Private Sub makePivot(sourceWs As Worksheet, DestWs As Worksheet, Optional startRow As Long = 2)
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, k As Integer, lastRow As Long
    Dim strTemp As String

    lastRow = startRow
    For i = startRow To sourceWs.Rows.Count
        strTemp = Trim(sourceWs.Cells(i, 1).Value & "")
        If (strTemp = "") Then Exit For
        '
        If (Val(sourceWs.Cells(i, 4).Value & "") <> 0) Or (Val(sourceWs.Cells(i, 7).Value & "") <> 0) Then
            For j = 1 To 3
                For k = 1 To 3
                    Call addNewRow(DestWs, lastRow, _
                                   (sourceWs.Cells(i, 1).Value & ""), (sourceWs.Cells(i, 2).Value & ""), (sourceWs.Cells(i, 3).Value & ""), _
                                   (sourceWs.Cells(1, 3 + j).Value & ""), (sourceWs.Cells(1, 6 + k).Value & ""), _
                                   (sourceWs.Cells(i, 3 + j).Value & ""), (sourceWs.Cells(i, 6 + k).Value & ""))
                    lastRow = lastRow + 1
                Next k
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub addNewRow(ws As Worksheet, inRow As Long _
                    , productI As String, currencyI As String, valueI As String _
                    , regionI As String, CustomerI As String _
                    , valu2 As String, value3 As String)
    '
    ws.Cells(inRow, 1).Value = productI
    ws.Cells(inRow, 2).Value = currencyI
    ws.Cells(inRow, 3).Value = valueI
    ws.Cells(inRow, 4).Value = regionI
    ws.Cells(inRow, 5).Value = CustomerI
    ws.Cells(inRow, 6).Value = valu2
    ws.Cells(inRow, 7).Value = value3
End Sub
```